# Set padding postInvalidate not removing padding on the bottom part on left side of puzzle

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi currently I'm working on a puzzle that slice and randomize one image. Upon setting up I have manually set the padding into 2 for all corners then after the puzzle is finished padding should be set to 0 on all corners as well to display the image in full. Problem is there is an odd thing that happen wherein only the right side of the puzzle removes the padding completely while the other side still has it's padding on the bottom part. This only happens on devices with lower specs. (Nexus One and alike)

Here's my code for the setting of padding after completing the puzzle:

```
if(true){                   
    enable_puzzle = false;
    for (int i=0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++){
        LinearLayout cont = (LinearLayout) parent.getChildAt(i);
        for (int c = 0; c < cont.getChildCount(); c++){
            View v  = cont.getChildAt(c);
            v.setClickable(false);
            v.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            v.postInvalidate();
        }
        cont.postInvalidate();  //Tried this didn't work
    }
    parent.postInvalidate(); //Tried this didn't work
}
```

for better understanding of how I placed my layout it's pretty simple. I have a linearLayout that in horizontal orientation which holds the imageViews which will be places into the parent container in vertical orientation.

Here's the screenshot for sample.

The puzzle on create (see odd padding on the bottom part on left side)

[image: Puzzle 1]

And upon completing:

[image]

This is the screenshot on my Nexus S emulator. Same thing happen on real device with lower specs.

UPDATE:

Upon checking it appears that the main cause was the width of the container for the images. Since I have a 4x4 puzzle and uses weight instead of fixed sizes the width for each images is not evenly distributed causing a 1px/dp difference. Now the only problem is on how can I get the width of the parent horizontal layout to be divided and round up to get an even result for each imageviews?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this, you can create a listener something like onPuzzelCompleteListener(), something that you are doing even now to remove the padding. Here you can show an ImageView with the complete image. This should solve your padding issue as for now.

Comment: Yeah that was what I did for now although I will keep of looking for a better solution for this.